# Can't map json property from Tumblr response with Jackson

Tags: android, json, jackson, tumblr

Ok, this thing is driving me nuts!

I have the following response from Tumblr:

```
{
"meta": {
    "status": 200,
    "msg": "OK"
},
"response": {
    "blog": {
        "title": "heavy metal broke my \u2665",
        "name": "crawlingindark",
        "posts": 22362,
        "url": "http:\/\/crawlingindark.tumblr.com\/",
        "updated": 1447328080,
        "description": "\u003Ccenter\u003EI\u0027m \u003Ca href=\u0022http:\/\/crawlingindark.tumblr.com\/tagged\/me\u0022\u003ENeno\u003C\/a\u003E - 20 years old \n\u003Cp\u003Eand i love music\n\u003Cp\u003E.\n\u003Ccenter\u003E - m u l t i f a n d o m  -\n\u003Cp\u003E ..............................................\n\u003Cp\u003E  my \u003Ca href=\u0022http:\/\/crawlingindark.tumblr.com\/tagged\/my+edits\u0022\u003Eedits\u003C\/a\u003E \/ \u003Ca href=\u0022http:\/\/crawlingindark.tumblr.com\/tagged\/gifs\u0022\u003Egifs\u003C\/a\u003E",
        "is_nsfw": false,
        "ask": true,
        "ask_page_title": "Ask Shit",
        "ask_anon": true,
        "submission_page_title": "Submit",
        "share_likes": true,
        "likes": 14065
    },
    "posts": [{
        "blog_name": "crawlingindark",
        "id": 132110495244,
        "post_url": "http:\/\/crawlingindark.tumblr.com\/post\/132110495244",
        "slug": "",
        "type": "photo",
        "date": "2015-10-28 22:59:16 GMT",
        "timestamp": 1446073156,
        "state": "published",
        "format": "html",
        "reblog_key": "3PWT3Isv",
        "tags": [],
        "short_url": "http:\/\/tmblr.co\/ZlSQww1x2PYuC",
        "summary": "",
        "recommended_source": null,
        "recommended_color": null,
        "highlighted": [],
        "note_count": 319,
        "source_url": "http:\/\/paramass.tumblr.com\/post\/132100950816",
        "source_title": "paramass",
        "caption": "",
        "reblog": {
            "tree_html": "",
            "comment": ""
        },
        "trail": [],
        "photoset_layout": "11",
        "photos": [{
            "caption": "",
            "alt_sizes": [{
                "url": "https:\/\/40.media.tumblr.com\/d17078742be254f1ba709fa3a4f28dc5\/tumblr_nwritjzxzs1sdaok0o1_1280.png",
                "width": 800,
                "height": 600
            }, {
                "url": "https:\/\/41.media.tumblr.com\/d17078742be254f1ba709fa3a4f28dc5\/tumblr_nwritjzxzs1sdaok0o1_500.png",
                "width": 500,
                "height": 375
            }, {
                "url": "https:\/\/40.media.tumblr.com\/d17078742be254f1ba709fa3a4f28dc5\/tumblr_nwritjzxzs1sdaok0o1_400.png",
                "width": 400,
                "height": 300
            }, {
                "url": "https:\/\/40.media.tumblr.com\/d17078742be254f1ba709fa3a4f28dc5\/tumblr_nwritjzxzs1sdaok0o1_250.png",
                "width": 250,
                "height": 188
            }, {
                "url": "https:\/\/41.media.tumblr.com\/d17078742be254f1ba709fa3a4f28dc5\/tumblr_nwritjzxzs1sdaok0o1_100.png",
                "width": 100,
                "height": 75
            }, {
                "url": "https:\/\/36.media.tumblr.com\/d17078742be254f1ba709fa3a4f28dc5\/tumblr_nwritjzxzs1sdaok0o1_75sq.png",
                "width": 75,
                "height": 75
            }],
            "original_size": {
                "url": "https:\/\/40.media.tumblr.com\/d17078742be254f1ba709fa3a4f28dc5\/tumblr_nwritjzxzs1sdaok0o1_1280.png",
                "width": 800,
                "height": 600
            }
        }, {
            "caption": "",
            "alt_sizes": [{
                "url": "https:\/\/36.media.tumblr.com\/c63bb95138bd9fd935940405986e27b0\/tumblr_nwritjzxzs1sdaok0o2_1280.png",
                "width": 800,
                "height": 600
            }, {
                "url": "https:\/\/40.media.tumblr.com\/c63bb95138bd9fd935940405986e27b0\/tumblr_nwritjzxzs1sdaok0o2_500.png",
                "width": 500,
                "height": 375
            }, {
                "url": "https:\/\/40.media.tumblr.com\/c63bb95138bd9fd935940405986e27b0\/tumblr_nwritjzxzs1sdaok0o2_400.png",
                "width": 400,
                "height": 300
            }, {
                "url": "https:\/\/41.media.tumblr.com\/c63bb95138bd9fd935940405986e27b0\/tumblr_nwritjzxzs1sdaok0o2_250.png",
                "width": 250,
                "height": 188
            }, {
                "url": "https:\/\/41.media.tumblr.com\/c63bb95138bd9fd935940405986e27b0\/tumblr_nwritjzxzs1sdaok0o2_100.png",
                "width": 100,
                "height": 75
            }, {
                "url": "https:\/\/40.media.tumblr.com\/c63bb95138bd9fd935940405986e27b0\/tumblr_nwritjzxzs1sdaok0o2_75sq.png",
                "width": 75,
                "height": 75
            }],
            "original_size": {
                "url": "https:\/\/36.media.tumblr.com\/c63bb95138bd9fd935940405986e27b0\/tumblr_nwritjzxzs1sdaok0o2_1280.png",
                "width": 800,
                "height": 600
            }
        }]
    }, {
        "blog_name": "crawlingindark",
        "id": 132105216164,
        "post_url": "http:\/\/crawlingindark.tumblr.com\/post\/132105216164",
        "slug": "",
        "type": "photo",
        "date": "2015-10-28 21:29:22 GMT",
        "timestamp": 1446067762,
        "state": "published",
        "format": "html",
        "reblog_key": "aSVzZOdQ",
        "tags": [],
        "short_url": "http:\/\/tmblr.co\/ZlSQww1x25Q2a",
        "summary": "",
        "recommended_source": null,
        "recommended_color": null,
        "highlighted": [],
        "note_count": 223,
        "source_url": "http:\/\/paramass.tumblr.com\/post\/132037729414",
        "source_title": "paramass",
        "caption": "",
        "reblog": {
            "tree_html": "",
            "comment": ""
        },
        "trail": [],
        "image_permalink": "http:\/\/crawlingindark.tumblr.com\/image\/132105216164",
        "photos": [{
            "caption": "",
            "alt_sizes": [{
                "url": "https:\/\/41.media.tumblr.com\/e53498ccbe5fbd27605491dfe206117b\/tumblr_nwriitRseS1sdaok0o1_1280.png",
                "width": 667,
                "height": 934
            }, {
                "url": "https:\/\/36.media.tumblr.com\/e53498ccbe5fbd27605491dfe206117b\/tumblr_nwriitRseS1sdaok0o1_500.png",
                "width": 500,
                "height": 700
            }, {
                "url": "https:\/\/41.media.tumblr.com\/e53498ccbe5fbd27605491dfe206117b\/tumblr_nwriitRseS1sdaok0o1_400.png",
                "width": 400,
                "height": 560
            }, {
                "url": "https:\/\/41.media.tumblr.com\/e53498ccbe5fbd27605491dfe206117b\/tumblr_nwriitRseS1sdaok0o1_250.png",
                "width": 250,
                "height": 350
            }, {
                "url": "https:\/\/36.media.tumblr.com\/e53498ccbe5fbd27605491dfe206117b\/tumblr_nwriitRseS1sdaok0o1_100.png",
                "width": 100,
                "height": 140
            }, {
                "url": "https:\/\/40.media.tumblr.com\/e53498ccbe5fbd27605491dfe206117b\/tumblr_nwriitRseS1sdaok0o1_75sq.png",
                "width": 75,
                "height": 75
            }],
            "original_size": {
                "url": "https:\/\/41.media.tumblr.com\/e53498ccbe5fbd27605491dfe206117b\/tumblr_nwriitRseS1sdaok0o1_1280.png",
                "width": 667,
                "height": 934
            }
        }]
    }],
    "total_posts": 21670
}
```

}

which is a response for the photos of a tumblr blog.

I then have the classes, generated for Jackson, with the help of http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org, that are the following:

The post:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "blog_name",
    "id",
    "post_url",
    "slug",
    "type",
    "date",
    "timestamp",
    "state",
    "format",
    "reblog_key",
    "tags",
    "short_url",
    "summary",
    "recommended_source",
    "recommended_color",
    "highlighted",
    "note_count",
    "source_url",
    "source_title",
    "caption",
    "reblog",
    "trail",
    "photoset_layout",
    "photos",
    "image_permalink"
})
public class Post {

    @JsonProperty("blog_name")
    private String blogName;
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;
    @JsonProperty("post_url")
    private String postUrl;
    @JsonProperty("slug")
    private String slug;
    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String type;
    @JsonProperty("date")
    private String date;
    @JsonProperty("timestamp")
    private Long timestamp;
    @JsonProperty("state")
    private String state;
    @JsonProperty("format")
    private String format;
    @JsonProperty("reblog_key")
    private String reblogKey;
    @JsonProperty("tags")
    private List<Object> tags = new ArrayList<Object>();
    @JsonProperty("short_url")
    private String shortUrl;
    @JsonProperty("summary")
    private String summary;
    @JsonProperty("recommended_source")
    private Object recommendedSource;
    @JsonProperty("recommended_color")
    private Object recommendedColor;
    @JsonProperty("highlighted")
    private List<Object> highlighted = new ArrayList<Object>();
    @JsonProperty("note_count")
    private Long noteCount;
    @JsonProperty("source_url")
    private String sourceUrl;
    @JsonProperty("source_title")
    private String sourceTitle;
    @JsonProperty("caption")
    private String caption;
    @JsonProperty("reblog")
    private se.onemanstudio.linkinpark.api.providers.photos.objects.tumblr.Reblog reblog;
    @JsonProperty("trail")
    private List<Object> trail = new ArrayList<Object>();
    @JsonProperty("photoset_layout")
    private String photosetLayout;
    @JsonProperty("photos")
    private List<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<Photo>();
    @JsonProperty("image_permalink")
    private String imagePermalink;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     * 
     */
    public Post() {
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param summary
     * @param sourceTitle
     * @param noteCount
     * @param state
     * @param highlighted
     * @param date
     * @param type
     * @param sourceUrl
     * @param recommendedColor
     * @param reblog
     * @param timestamp
     * @param id
     * @param blogName
     * @param trail
     * @param shortUrl
     * @param tags
     * @param photosetLayout
     * @param postUrl
     * @param caption
     * @param format
     * @param photos
     * @param reblogKey
     * @param imagePermalink
     * @param recommendedSource
     * @param slug
     */
    public Post(String blogName, Long id, String postUrl, String slug, String type, String date, Long timestamp, String state, String format, String reblogKey, List<Object> tags, String shortUrl, String summary, Object recommendedSource, Object recommendedColor, List<Object> highlighted, Long noteCount, String sourceUrl, String sourceTitle, String caption, se.onemanstudio.linkinpark.api.providers.photos.objects.tumblr.Reblog reblog, List<Object> trail, String photosetLayout, List<Photo> photos, String imagePermalink) {
        this.blogName = blogName;
        this.id = id;
        this.postUrl = postUrl;
        this.slug = slug;
        this.type = type;
        this.date = date;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.state = state;
        this.format = format;
        this.reblogKey = reblogKey;
        this.tags = tags;
        this.shortUrl = shortUrl;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.recommendedSource = recommendedSource;
        this.recommendedColor = recommendedColor;
        this.highlighted = highlighted;
        this.noteCount = noteCount;
        this.sourceUrl = sourceUrl;
        this.sourceTitle = sourceTitle;
        this.caption = caption;
        this.reblog = reblog;
        this.trail = trail;
        this.photosetLayout = photosetLayout;
        this.photos = photos;
        this.imagePermalink = imagePermalink;

        Toolkit.Logd("POST", "Created a post with source_url: " + this.sourceUrl + " and source_title: " + this.sourceTitle);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The blogName
     */
    @JsonProperty("blog_name")
    public String getBlogName() {
        return blogName;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param blogName
     *     The blog_name
     */
    @JsonProperty("blog_name")
    public void setBlogName(String blogName) {
        this.blogName = blogName;
    }

    public Post withBlogName(String blogName) {
        this.blogName = blogName;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The id
     */
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param id
     *     The id
     */
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Post withId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The postUrl
     */
    @JsonProperty("post_url")
    public String getPostUrl() {
        return postUrl;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param postUrl
     *     The post_url
     */
    @JsonProperty("post_url")
    public void setPostUrl(String postUrl) {
        this.postUrl = postUrl;
    }

    public Post withPostUrl(String postUrl) {
        this.postUrl = postUrl;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The photosetLayout
     */
    @JsonProperty("photoset_layout")
    public String getPhotosetLayout() {
        return photosetLayout;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param photosetLayout
     *     The photoset_layout
     */
    @JsonProperty("photoset_layout")
    public void setPhotosetLayout(String photosetLayout) {
        this.photosetLayout = photosetLayout;
    }

    public Post withPhotosetLayout(String photosetLayout) {
        this.photosetLayout = photosetLayout;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The photos
     */
    @JsonProperty("photos")
    public List<Photo> getPhotos() {
        return photos;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param photos
     *     The photos
     */
    @JsonProperty("photos")
    public void setPhotos(List<Photo> photos) {
        this.photos = photos;
    }

    public Post withPhotos(List<Photo> photos) {
        this.photos = photos;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The imagePermalink
     */
    @JsonProperty("image_permalink")
    public String getImagePermalink() {
        return imagePermalink;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param imagePermalink
     *     The image_permalink
     */
    @JsonProperty("image_permalink")
    public void setImagePermalink(String imagePermalink) {
        this.imagePermalink = imagePermalink;
    }

    public Post withImagePermalink(String imagePermalink) {
        this.imagePermalink = imagePermalink;
        return this;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

    public Post withAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
        return this;
    }

}
```

and the photo:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "caption",
    "alt_sizes",
    "original_size"
})
public class Photo {

    @JsonProperty("caption")
    private String caption;
    @JsonProperty("alt_sizes")
    private List<AltSize> altSizes = new ArrayList<AltSize>();
    @JsonProperty("original_size")
    private OriginalSize originalSize;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     * 
     */
    public Photo() {
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param originalSize
     * @param altSizes
     * @param caption
     */
    public Photo(String caption, List<AltSize> altSizes, OriginalSize originalSize) {
        this.caption = caption;
        this.altSizes = altSizes;
        this.originalSize = originalSize;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The caption
     */
    @JsonProperty("caption")
    public String getCaption() {
        return caption;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param caption
     *     The caption
     */
    @JsonProperty("caption")
    public void setCaption(String caption) {
        this.caption = caption;
    }

    public Photo withCaption(String caption) {
        this.caption = caption;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The altSizes
     */
    @JsonProperty("alt_sizes")
    public List<AltSize> getAltSizes() {
        return altSizes;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param altSizes
     *     The alt_sizes
     */
    @JsonProperty("alt_sizes")
    public void setAltSizes(List<AltSize> altSizes) {
        this.altSizes = altSizes;
    }

    public Photo withAltSizes(List<AltSize> altSizes) {
        this.altSizes = altSizes;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The originalSize
     */
    @JsonProperty("original_size")
    public OriginalSize getOriginalSize() {
        return originalSize;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param originalSize
     *     The original_size
     */
    @JsonProperty("original_size")
    public void setOriginalSize(OriginalSize originalSize) {
        this.originalSize = originalSize;
    }

    public Photo withOriginalSize(OriginalSize originalSize) {
        this.originalSize = originalSize;
        return this;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

    public Photo withAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
        return this;
    }

}
```

The OriginalSize.java file, as generated is the following:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "url",
    "width",
    "height"
})

public class OriginalSize {

    @JsonProperty("url")
    private String url;
    @JsonProperty("width")
    private Long width;
    @JsonProperty("height")
    private Long height;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     * 
     */
    public OriginalSize() {
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param height
     * @param width
     * @param url
     */
    public OriginalSize(String url, Long width, Long height) {
        this.url = url;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The url
     */
    @JsonProperty("url")
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param url
     *     The url
     */
    @JsonProperty("url")
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public OriginalSize withUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The width
     */
    @JsonProperty("width")
    public Long getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param width
     *     The width
     */
    @JsonProperty("width")
    public void setWidth(Long width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public OriginalSize withWidth(Long width) {
        this.width = width;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The height
     */
    @JsonProperty("height")
    public Long getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param height
     *     The height
     */
    @JsonProperty("height")
    public void setHeight(Long height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public OriginalSize withHeight(Long height) {
        this.height = height;
        return this;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

    public OriginalSize withAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
        return this;
    }

}
```

The AltSize.java as it was generated:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "url",
    "width",
    "height"
})
public class AltSize {

    @JsonProperty("url")
    private String url;
    @JsonProperty("width")
    private Long width;
    @JsonProperty("height")
    private Long height;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     * 
     */
    public AltSize() {
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param height
     * @param width
     * @param url
     */
    public AltSize(String url, Long width, Long height) {
        this.url = url;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The url
     */
    @JsonProperty("url")
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param url
     *     The url
     */
    @JsonProperty("url")
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public AltSize withUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The width
     */
    @JsonProperty("width")
    public Long getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param width
     *     The width
     */
    @JsonProperty("width")
    public void setWidth(Long width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public AltSize withWidth(Long width) {
        this.width = width;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The height
     */
    @JsonProperty("height")
    public Long getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param height
     *     The height
     */
    @JsonProperty("height")
    public void setHeight(Long height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public AltSize withHeight(Long height) {
        this.height = height;
        return this;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

    public AltSize withAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
        return this;
    }

}
```

which all seem to be fine and according to the documentation.

I then iterate through the content with the following code:

```
public static ArrayList<GenericPhoto> extractPhotosFromTumblrContent(TumblrPhotoDataWrapper tumbrlData) {
    ArrayList<GenericPhoto> mPictures = new ArrayList<>();

Toolkit.Logd(TAG, "Working on the tumblr '" + tumbrlData.getSource() + "' which has " + tumbrlData.getTumblrRootContent().getResponse().getPosts().size() + " posts...");

for (Post post : tumbrlData.getTumblrRootContent().getResponse().getPosts()) {
    Toolkit.Logd(TAG, "The post with id " + post.getId() + " has " + post.getPhotos().size() + " photos");

    for (Photo photo : post.getPhotos()) {
        GenericPhoto wi = new GenericPhoto();

        wi.setPostId(post.getId());
        wi.setTimestamp(post.getTimestamp());

        //wi.setCaption(photo.getOriginalSize().getUrl());

        int totalAlternativeSizesOfPhotos = photo.getAltSizes().size();
        //wi.setUrlSmall(photo.getAltSizes().get(totalAlternativeSizesOfPhotos - 2).getUrl());
        //wi.setUrlLarge(photo.getOriginalSize().getUrl());
        //wi.setUrlSmall(photo.getAltSizes().get(2).getUrl());

        Toolkit.Logd(TAG, "The post id is " + post.getId() + " and it has " + totalAlternativeSizesOfPhotos + " alternative sizes");

        mPictures.add(wi);
    }
}

Toolkit.Logd(TAG, "I extracted " + mPictures.size() + " from the tumblr " + tumbrlData.getSource());

return mPictures;
```

}

which just goes through all the pictures of the posts.

The problem is that even though the mapping detects correctly how many photos are at each post (i.e. 2, 5, 8), it also detects 0 alternative sizes and no original size of the photo. It is as if the mapping for each photo doesn't occur when Jackson does all its work.

I have tried recreating the classes with the jsonschema2pojo, cleaning the project, cleaning caches, but nothing seems to do work.

What can be the problem? Where else should I look?
Can it be something with Proguard? Can it be something with the configuration of the project at Android Studio?

The fact that Jackson works flawlessly with the parsing of RSS news feed, as well as the JSON response from YouTube makes me think that there is something wrong either with the Photos class or the configuration of some component.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you also show how OriginalSize and AltSize classes look like?

Comment: @dkarmazi, I added them. Also, further experimenting showed me that the problem is more general and occurs for all the fields that have underscore, "_", at their name! Even though I have the @JsonProperty("blog_name") at the blogName, it is still null.